# how to prevent the function from firing when an document.body.addEventListener("click") is created?

Tags: javascript

Basically I am making that when I click on a button with text "activate click listener body" a listener is created, and triggers it when I click on any part of the body.

But I want to prevent it from being executed the first time when I click on the button with text "activate click listener body" (currently when I click on the button, the `clickBody` function is executed).

I want the `clickBody` function to be executed when I click again once the click listener is created.

how can do it?

```js
function clickBody(){
  alert("click body");
}

function removeClickBody(){
  document.body.removeEventListener("click",clickBody);
}

function activateListenerClickBody(){
  document.body.addEventListener("click",clickBody);
}
```

```css
body{
  height:100vh;
  width:100wh;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button onclick="activateListenerClickBody()">Activate click listener body</button>
  <button onclick="removeClickBody()">Remove click listener</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this by stopping the propagation of the click event. You can use [`stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) to accomplish this. Here is an example of using that on the click handler of the button itself.

```js
function clickBody(){
  alert("click body");
}

function removeClickBody(){
  document.body.removeEventListener("click",clickBody);
}

function activateListenerClickBody(){
  document.body.addEventListener("click",clickBody);
}
```

```css
body{
  height:100vh;
  width:100wh;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="activateListenerClickBody(); event.stopPropagation();">Activate click listener body</button>
<button onclick="removeClickBody()">Remove click listener</button>
```